# flask-wtf editing a model using wtform Form constructor: pre-filling the form

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am reading the Flask Web Development book and came across this:

```
def edit_profile():
    form = EditProfileForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        current_user.name = form.name.data
        current_user.location = form.location.data
        current_user.about_me = form.about_me.data
        db.session.add(user)
        flash('Your profile has been updated.')
        return redirect(url_for('.user', username=current_user.username))
    form.name.data = current_user.name
    form.location.data = current_user.location
    form.about_me.data = current_user.about_me
    return render_template('edit_profile.html', form=form)
```

Basically, when the form is not posted or doesn't validate, this copies over the data from the current user. Now reading up on wtforms, I read this about the **init** method on a form:

```
obj – If formdata is empty or not provided, this object is checked for attributes
      matching form field names, which will be used for field values.
```

So I guess that means that we could write this (the sample below is my own):

```
def edit_post(post_id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    if current_user != post.author:
        abort(403)
    # Below is the line I am concerned about
    form = PostForm(formdata=request.form, obj=post)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(post)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('user', username=current_user.username))
    return render_template('post_form.html', form=form)
```

I figure that this should fill the form instance from the database model on GET, and from POST data after post. Testing this, it seems to work..

Now my question: is this way of writing an edit view correct? Or should I copy everything over field by field, like in the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading in a POST `MultiDict` is certainly the accepted way to map key/value pairs to your WTForms instance. Even more so, if you are using the Flask-WTF extension, this is automatically done for you, it is one of the perks that this extension brings you.

If you would crack open the code of Flask-WTF you would see that it inherits the `SecureForm` class of WTForms and tries to load in the Werkzeug POST MultiDict (called `formdata`) by default (if it is present). So loading in your form in your view like this:

```python
form = PostForm(obj=post)
```

Should be sufficient (if using Flask-WTF) to also fill the fields with POSTed data.

The way it is done in your book example is certainly not wrong, but creates a lot of unnecessary code and is error prone / redundant - one could forget to mention a field in the view that is declared in the WTForms instance.